# Sign Up vs. Add to Cart CTA for different product types' product detail pages

Tags: e-commerce, cta

So we have a webinar business that offers users the option to sign up for an upcoming webinar as well as a purchase a recording of a past webinar. Every webinar (upcoming and recorded) has it's own product detail page.

I am curious if it would be considered a best practice or intuitive to change the "sign up" CTA on the product detail page for upcoming webinars to "add to cart" for past webinar recording detail pages. My thought is that customers aren't actually "signing up" for a recorded webinar... they're just purchasing access to the recording.

Does this make sense to implement or am I only adding potential for confusion by having 2 different CTAs on these detail pages? I haven't seen any examples of this in the wild, so I was hoping for some thoughts/examples/direction from the group here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

welcome. Your instincts are correct that "Add to cart" is definitely a better CTA than "sign up". You'll want to hide the "sign up" button if the user can't sign up. "Add to cart" is fine for the remaining button if there are cues on the page that the webinar happened in the past, and the user can purchase a recording. If that's not possible, you might consider a CTA such as "Add recording to cart" or "Purchase recording".